# Upload to Firebase, with, and without image

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have this function for uploading images to Firebase:

```
 func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(self.completePhoneNumber).child("image.png")
        if let uploadData = self.selectedImage.pngData() {
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    completion(nil)
                } else {
                    storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                        print(url?.absoluteString)

                        completion(url?.absoluteString)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And it's getting called like this:

```
if (myTextFields.text != nil) {
            uploadMedia() { url in

                self.ref?.child("hosts").child(self.completePhoneNumber).setValue([

                    //Write data to firebase, and:    

                    "hostImageURL" : url
                ])

            }
        } else {    
            //Show error.    
}
```

This work fine as long as I have selected a image to upload. But if I try to write data to Firebase without the `url` nothing happens..
How can I do a: `if url == nil { do some other stuff }`

Comment: Are you trying to only image upload to Firebase Storage or uploading Firebase Database?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. What other stuff do you want to do in `if url == nil { do some other stuff }`? And what problem do you encounter when doing that?

Comment: You're not handling the error here `storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error)` so if there is one, you wouldn't know. Additionally and somewhat OT, this `.child(self.completePhoneNumber)` is a bad idea (IMO). Phone numbers change and if they do you'll have to read that node in, delete it, and write it back out *everywhere* it appears in your database. Better to set the node key with .childByAutoId and have the phone number as a child.